# Why does this C++ thread code trigger an abort() error?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am testing the new C++11 thread features. To do this, I start a thread by providing a lambda expression to its constructor:

```
   int main()
    {
        thread t([]() {
            cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
        });

        //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));

        cout << "I am done!" << endl;
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

But after I press a key (`getchar`), I get the error:

[image: Debug]

Can someone give a reason?

Comment: Because the `join` function is not called (i.e., `t.join();`).

Comment: So what? I understand that join() must only be called for the main thread to wait for the worker thread. In this case, there is no purpose in waiting, because I press a key.

Comment: and thus you leak a resource. A very, very expensive resource.

Comment: When the `thread` instance is destroyed, it must be either joined or detached, otherwise `terminate` is called. ([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread))

Comment: "there is no purpose in waiting" is at odds with [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread): `std::thread::~thread`:  destructs the thread object, underlying thread must be joined or detached

Comment: Is this a debugger error, or is this error thrown when running the console application standalone?  If this is a debugger error, it is Visual Studio telling you that a thread was aborted on exit, which is normal behavior - Visual Studio recognizes that an unfinished thread was terminated, and also, operating systems always close all resource handles associated with an application when the application terminates (this includes threads, file descriptors, allocated memory, etc).

Comment: It is a debugger error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is expected and the following explains how to avoid it.

From the [std::thread::~thread documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.

> A thread object does not have an associated thread (and is safe to destroy) after
>
> - it was default-constructed
> - it was moved from
> - join() has been called
> - detach() has been called

---

> So what? I understand that join() must only be called for the main thread to wait for the worker thread. In this case, there is no purpose in waiting, because I press a key.

Why is there no purpose in waiting? What happens if the `main` function finishes execution before the `std::cout` stream object is used by the thread (albeit unlikely it's still possible even though you have the `getchar()` call)? Is that global stream object still valid for use by the thread?

Comment: Ahh, I see. But what I don't understand is this. Suppose I write thread t([]() { ... }); and then on the next line write t.join() (in main). Still, t could finish before t.join() is called (in theory) and thus it calls std::terminate? 

Just to be sure, it is std::terminate that makes VS display a debug error, right?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Yes, it is perfectly fine for `t` to finish execution before `join` is called. The issue is that `join` needs to be called before the destructor of `t` is called (i.e., before the closing `}` brace of the `main` function). Therefore calling `join` immediately after `t` is constructed with the lambda expression will guarantee `t` finishes before the destructor of `t` is executed.

Comment: Aha! That's making sense... Still, is it the std::terminate called by t (because it is joinable) that causes VS to give the debug error? Or what means causes it?

Comment: Well `join` or `detach`.  The main thing is `joinable` needs to return `false`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the answer states that `detach` works as well as the fact that `joinable == true` is the reason `std::terminate` is called.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I think the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754215/why-does-this-c-thread-code-trigger-an-abort-error/35754331#comment59182519_35754215) provided by **Matt Jordan** explains this for you.

Comment: Will std::terminate from the thread cause the main program to terminate or just the thread?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen The `std::terminate` function is called by the destructor of the `std::thread` object. In this case the object is named `t` which is instantiated in the `main` function therefore `std::thread::~thread` is called in the context of the `main` thread (i.e., it's not called in the context of the thread created by the `t` object).

Comment: I see, so the program terminates.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Yes, the program terminates -- [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate] "In any case, `std::terminate` calls the currently installed `std::terminate_handler`. The default `std::terminate_handler` calls `std::abort`." [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort] "Causes abnormal program termination unless SIGABRT is being caught by a signal handler passed to signal and the handler does not return."